# kivy: Problem displaying some Persian / Arabic letters

Tags: python, kivy, arabic, kivymd

I am designing a desktop software based on Python and the kivy platform and I use Persian / Arabic language in the software. Using two libraries arabic_reshaper and bidi. But the problem is that two of the letters, the letters "ی" and "ر", are not displayed correctly. I am sure about the health of the font because, firstly, it works perfectly well in environments such as Photoshop and Word, and secondly, it is the most famous font of this language.But I dont know where the problem is that they are not displayed properly in kivy.My method is to change the font name to roboto and replace the kivy font folder fonts.

this is my code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''
#:import arabic_reshaper arabic_reshaper
#:import get_display bidi.algorithm.get_display

Screen:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        MDToolbar:
            title: get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape("ایران سنس"))

        MDLabel:
            halign: "center"
            text_language: "ar"
            base_direction: "rtl"
            shorten_from: "left"
            strip: True
            text:get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape("این یک متن نمونه برای تست می باشد"))
'''


class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


Test().run()
```

and this is result:

[image]

Does anyone know where the problem comes from?

Comment: It may be that using a different text provider would work better, but I'm not sure which if any might have better support.

Comment: Can you introduce another text provider? @inclement

Comment: it might be a limitation of the current rendering, first i would try with pillow, `pip install pillow` then run with `env KIVY_TEXT=pillow python main.py` but if that's not enough then you could need https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/7452 to be merged, there are linux wheels linked if that helps, otherwise you'll likely need a windows build.

Comment: Problem solved I talked to the font designer and the problem was solved with the font update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By communicating with the font support, the problem was finally solved by providing several updates (the problem was with the font).

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.lang import Builder
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display

Builder.load_string("""
<First>:
    Label:  
        text : root.bidi_text
        font_name : "iransans.ttf"

        
""")



class First(Screen):
    reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape("رضى")
    bidi_text = get_display(reshaped_text)


class Second(Screen):
    pass

class ArabApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(First(name="First"))
        return sm



ArabApp().run()
```

Comment: Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].